# Ways of speeding up a loop that iterates over a large array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm looking to speed up the code below which loops through each voxel in `brain` that has been split into regions (numbered 0 to 50), and reassigns that region with a corresponding value (found in the array `region_vals` which contains 51 numbers). `brain` is a numpy.ndarray. As the dimensions of the brain array are 182x218x182 it takes around 12 seconds to finish this loop.

```py
import numpy as np

# Sample data
brain = np.random.randint(10, size=(6,5,5))
region_vals = np.random.randint(250, size=11)

# Iterate through each voxel in the brain
for x in range(0, brain.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, brain.shape[1]):
        for z in range(0, brain.shape[2]):

            region = brain[x][y][z]  # Get region number

            # Reassign voxel value
            brain[x][y][z] = region_vals[region]
```

Multi-threading is not an option here as I am already running this code in parallel.

Is there a way of speeding up the loop or removing the loop entirely?

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose yes you are right. Removing those parts reduced run time from 12 seconds down to 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment - I'll put it back: I bet the critical part in the middle is the bottleneck and not the loop overhead.

Comment: Numpy arrays are suitable for bulk operations, *not* iteration and indexing. Ideally, use native numpy operations. However, we cannot really say how to do this best without knowing what ``region_vals[region]`` is actually doing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `region_vals` is an array of 51 float values, whereas `region` is an integer. `region_vals[region]` just finds the value for that region.

Comment: @tdelaney I have provided some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just use `brain` (initial) as indices for `region_vals` in a one-liner if `region_vals` is also a numpy array:
`brain = region_vals[brain]`

Comment: With the caveats that 1) `region_vals` needs to be a numpy array,  2) `brain` needs to be an numpy array of `int`s, and 3) this creates a new array rather than modifying in place. . . . this is utterly brilliant.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly with the caveats that @FrankYellin gave. Caveats one and two in particular are what tripped me up and stopped this from working in my code in the past. Thank you!